# Cyper Merge on Optional Match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to see if node :Customer exists based on a relationship in my optional match. I then want to create some relationships to my customer if they have an order. I am not sure what is the correct syntax for this.

```
MERGE (o:Order {account: 'j593jfsh', id: '35353'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Customer)-[:HAS_ORDER]->(o)
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_SESSION]->(s)
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_ORDER]->(o)
WHERE c IS NOT NULL"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you could do this is to use [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) in place of the OPTIONAL MATCH. This would collect all customers having orders into a list, and then you could use FOREACH to MERGE the relationships. If there are no customers, the list will be empty, and FOREACH will have nothing to process.

```
...
MERGE (o:Order {account: 'j593jfsh', id: '35353'})
WITH o, s, [(c:Customer)-[:HAS_ORDER]->(o) | c] as customers
FOREACH (c in customers | 
 MERGE (c)-[:HAS_SESSION]->(s)
 MERGE (c)-[:HAS_ORDER]->(o)
)
...
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks